# asp.net if else without codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to implement if else in ASP file. But it is giving 500 internal server error.

Earlier code was

```
<title><%=title_tag%></title>
```

But I've tried to do

```
<%= if(meta_keywords_tag.IndexOf("MI")!= -1){ %>
<title>MI</title>
 <% }
else { %>
<title><%=title_tag%></title>
<% } %>
```

When I remove this, It works fine. I'm unable to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: meta_keywords_tag is not happy with IndexOf. either it does not declared or none assigned

Comment: Even if I remove that and just use if(true) instead of (meta_keywords_tag.IndexOf("MI")!= -1) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After commenting, it seems you have a typo at

```
<%= if(meta_keywords_tag.IndexOf("MI")!= -1){ %>
```

goes to

```
<% if(meta_keywords_tag.IndexOf("MI")!= -1){ %>
<title>MI</title>
 <% }
else { %>
<title><%=title_tag%></title>
<% } %>
```

Comment: give a shot with if (true) bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this

```
<title><%If 2 > 1 Then%>
       MI
   <% Else %>
        <%=title_tag%>
    <%End If %>
        </title>
```

This works like a charm, But the issue is that I want to use a code behind variable in if statement

```
<%If ("" <%=title_tag%>"".ToString().Contains("MI") = True) Then%>
```

It is not working.